# High kinetic basicity of alkoxides compared to alkyls

Tags: acid-base, organometallic-compounds

I'm reading something at the moment where they state:

> This reagent has enhanced basicity as it benefits from the high kinetic basicity of alkoxides compared to alkyls.

This is in the context of organometallics so we're talking about a negatively charged alkoxide ligand versus a negatively charged alkyl ligand.

So why do alkoxides have a higher kinetic basicity than alkyls? I thought this might be because the negative charge on $\ce{-O}$ is more accessible for doing the deprotonation than the neagtive charge on $\ce{-CH2}$ due to the bonded hydrogens. Is this correct or are there other factors at play?